# Best way to check if an item exists in sql server ce?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

Ok so I'm basically trying to determine which way is more efficient performance wise when checking if items exist in a database.

I'm using LINQ to SQL on WP7 with SQL Server CE.

I'm going to be importing multiple objects into the database. Now there is a pretty good possibility that some of those objects already exist in the database so I need to check each item as they come in and if its already there, skip it, otherwise add it.

There were two approaches that came to mind. The first was using a foreach and checking if an object exists in the db with the same name:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    //Make individual call to db for every item
    var possibleItem = /*SQL SERVER STATEMENT WITH WHERE CONDITION*/;
}
```

Making individual calls to the db though sounds pretty resource intensive. So the other idea was to do a full select on all the objects in the db and store them in the list. And then pretty much do the same concept with the foreach except now I don't have to connect to the db, I have direct access to the list. What are your thoughts on these approaches? Is there a better way?

Comment: when in doubt just try - normaly you should try to change things so you don't have to foreach and check each - in most cases you can do a Where and then foreach based on this query (if you know what I mean) but without code you just cannot say. But I think that the SqlCe will do some indexing in memory so it should not be slower than a Where based on a list (which has bad query performance of O(n))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can easily sort your items you could make a select from the database and step through the list while reading through the database to determine which items are new. That should be much faster than multiple selects while preserving memory.

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while(reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
  {
    var id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    // test how id compares to the memory list
  }
}
```

But if memory if of no concern, I'd probably just read all keys from the database into memory for simplicity.

Comment: Yes since this is a mobile app, memory is a key issue here. I'm not sure what you mean by stepping through a list while reading through a database. I didn't know this was possible. How do you do that?

Comment: I added a short example of using a datareader on a command object. Im on a phone right now, so Im sorry if the formatting sucks.

Comment: Ok, I'm out of my depth there I'm afraid. But there is Linq2Sql, so why not create a query and loop out the objects through it? That should work the same as long as no tracking makes the objects stay in memory.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Yes I'm thinking that would be the best approach. I'm sceptical about querying the database over and over again doesn't sound right. Also I have noticed that while the querying isn't slow with a single request, it does take longer when doing multiple requests.